# Hello metatable.__len world

Tags: lua, metatable

A beginner's question about Lua and *metatables*, with a example as simple as an Hello‑World, involving the `len` event, which unfortunately does not returns the expected result (I'm using Lua 5.1 installed from Ubuntu's official repository).

## The case

Here is the example:

```
Test_Type = {};

function Test_Type.__len (o)
   return 1;
end;

function new_test ()
   local result = {};
   setmetatable(result, Test_Type);
   return result;
end;

do
   local a_test = new_test();
   print (#a_test);
   print(getmetatable(a_test).__len(a_test));
end;
```

And the result I get:

```
0
1
```

I was expecting the first print statement to display `1`, but it displays `0`, to my big surprise.

What did I missed?

According to [Lua Reference Manual — Metatables and Metamethods](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.4), the `#` is equivalent to this:

```
function len_event (op)
  if type(op) == "string" then
    return strlen(op)      -- primitive string length
  else
    local h = metatable(op).__len
    if h then
      return (h(op))       -- call handler with the operand
    elseif type(op) == "table" then
      return #op              -- primitive table length
    else  -- no handler available: error
      error(···)
    end
  end
end
```

So `print (#a_test);` and `print(getmetatable(a_test).__len(a_test));` should result into the same, isn't it?

By the way, why is the above excerpt from the Reference Manual refers to `metatable(op)` while it should be `getmetatable(op)`? At least I've tried `print(metatable(a_test).__len(a_test));`, and it ends into an error.

## Answer

As *Nneonneo* noticed, this is an issue with the Lua version in use. Lua 5.2 seems to be required for the above to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaFaq:

> #### Why doesn't the __gc and __len metamethods work on tables?
>
> `__len` on tables is scheduled to be supported in 5.2. See LuaFiveTwo.

Since you're using 5.1, `__len` on tables does not work. Indeed, running your code on Lua 5.2 produces

```
1
1
```

as expected.

Comment: If you're looking for a Lua 5.1 implementation that supports __len, try LuaJIT 2 with LUAJIT_LUA52_COMPAT enabled.

Comment: You mean `-DLUAJIT_ENABLE_LUA52COMPAT`?

Comment: @**Nneonneo**. I had notice the RM document referred to Lua 5.2 while I was using Lua 5.1, but quickly dropped the idea this could be the cause. So it is. Thanks for the pointer to the Lua FAQ.

@**Deco**. I just installed luajit-2.0.0-beta4 in Ubuntu Maverick. Unfortunately, the result is the same, but still thanks for the pointers: now I know about LuaJIT.

Comment: @Hibou57: Most likely, the Ubuntu distro ships without `-DLUAJIT_ENABLE_LUA52COMPAT`. You'd probably have to compile your own version to get it to work.

Comment: That's OK, the case works (after compiling LuaJIT from source).