# implementing torch's __len__ meta function

Tags: lua, torch

In our [torch-dataframe](https://github.com/AlexMili/torch-dataframe) project we're trying to implement `__len__` meta function as follows :

```
MyClass.__len__ = argcheck{
    {name="self", type="MyClass"},
    {name="other", type="MyClass"},
    call=function(self, other)
    return self.n_rows
end}
```

This works in Lua 5.2 and 5.3 but for Lua 5.1, luajit 2.0 and 2.1 the returned variable is not the actual row number but 0. The sense is that it returns a new instance of MyClass but it's hard to understand why. There is a note about __len changing [here](https://www.corsix.org/content/look-lua-52-work3) but that's the best doc hint we've managed to locate so far.

A little surprising is the need for two arguments. When `argcheck` is provided with a single argument version:

```
MyClass.__len__ = argcheck{
   {name = "self", type = "MyClass"},
   call=function(self)
   return self.n_rows
end}
```

it throws:

```
[string "argcheck"]:28: 
Arguments:

({
   self = MyClass  -- 
})


Got: MyClass, MyClass
```

We currently rely on the `argcheck` overload operator for handling this:

```
MyClass.__len__ = argcheck{
    {name="self", type="MyClass"},
    {name="other", type="MyClass"},
    call=function(self, other)
    return self.n_rows
end}

MyClass.__len__ = argcheck{
    overload=MyClass.__len__,
    {name="self", type="MyClass"},
    call=function(self)
    return self.n_rows
end}
```

For more details here is the full class and the travis report :

- [Full metatable class](https://github.com/AlexMili/torch-dataframe/blob/develop/Extensions/metatable.lua)
- [Travis report](https://travis-ci.org/AlexMili/torch-dataframe/builds/135456976)

### Test case

Here's a full test-case that works as expected in 5.2 and 5.3 that perhaps illustrates the problem in a more concise way that the full package:

```
require 'torch'
local argcheck = require "argcheck"

local MyClass = torch.class("MyClass")

function MyClass:init()
    self.n_rows = 0
end

MyClass.__len__ = argcheck{
    {name = "self", type = "MyClass"},
    {name = "other", type = "MyClass"},
    call=function(self, other)
    print(self.n_rows)
    print(other.n_rows)
    return(self.n_rows)
end}

local obj = MyClass.new()
obj.n_rows = 1
local n = #obj
print(n)
```

This prints as expected:

```
1
1
1
```

Comment: Lua has `__len` metamethod not `__len__`

Comment: @moteus the torch class actually uses this naming convention

Comment: Why do you need to argcheck `self` here? Is it just for documenting the method (via the ad hoc `doc` attribute not illustrated here)?

Comment: @deltheil - the `self` will always be in the arguments when using `:`, I'm not sure why this would differ in the `#` syntactic sugar. The single argument call is only working with the `:__len__` call while the `#` always provides two identical arguments. I've checked that we're not returning the wrong `MyClass` instance but no matter which one chooses the code fails *outside the 5.2* version.

Comment: If you dump the stack right before this [call](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/69d7a01760a43f530b8da0d9c022042c55a559e0/lib/luaT/luaT.c#L1202) it looks like `function table table` so `__len__` is called with 2 arguments (twice the same object).

Comment: Yes but it seems it's not the case on other versions than 5.2. It looks like a first call is made on a single argument `__len__` method and then on the two argument method, justifying the overload. We don't understand why the overloading is needed and why it returns 0 with other versions (which is our final problem)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766510/hello-metatable-len-world). There simply is [no support](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaFaq) for it in 5.1:

> __len on tables is scheduled to be supported in 5.2. See LuaFiveTwo.